# How to execute "make; make install" inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, gnu-make, configure, nagios

I need to automate the installation of the NRPE agent inside a bash script. How do I "make; make install" in a remote directory? Here's the code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.tar.gz
do
    tar zxf "$f" -C /home/$USER/
done

sudo useradd -s /sbin/nologin -M nagios

/home/$USER/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/configure --enable-command-args --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib64/
```

So after the "configure" part ends I need to execute "make; make install". Also, is there any way to optimize the current script?

Comment: remember to check the status of the executed commands and proceed appropriately

Comment: Fixed the "currentuser". Don't really know why I added it in the first place.

Comment: @Khanna111 Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Lets hope there is no `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in any of the tars.

Comment: @eckes I use a dedicated folder for the NRPE installation files

Comment: @jsteppe your script uses the homedir, that’s risky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help with [Khanna111's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390882/how-to-execute-make-make-install-inside-a-bash-script/55391081#comment97503138_55390882):

```
cd /home/$USER/nagios-plugins-2.2.1 || exit 1
configure <options> && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: So if I "cd" inside a script, it will operate from the directory it changed to?

Comment: Yes, no matter which operating system you use.